c++ unordered set range-erase bug

std::unordered_set<Vector2i> basicWalls = FindWalls(floorPositions, cardinal2D);
std::unordered_set<Vector2i> cornerWalls = FindWalls(floorPositions, Diagonal2D);

    printf("basic walls size: %d, corner walls size: %d\n", basicWalls.size(), cornerWalls.size());

cornerWalls.erase(basicWalls.begin(),basicWalls.end());//to delete duplicates

    printf("basic walls size: %d, corner walls size: %d\n", basicWalls.size(), cornerWalls.size());

Wall_World_positions.reserve(basicWalls.size() + cornerWalls.size());
Wall_CollisionBox.reserve(basicWalls.size() + cornerWalls.size());

LoadAppropriateWallTiles(basicWalls, floorPositions, cardinal2D);

unordered set 'range-erase' invalidates basicwalls's iterator, not that of 'cornerWalls'  whose elements are being erased.
cplusplus.com says 'Only the iterators and references to the elements removed are invalidated.'
Am I missing something, shouldn't it be the other way around? I am not trying to delete anything inside basicWalls.
when I comment out cornerWalls.erase, 'LoadAppropriateWallTiles' works as intented
error png

cornerWalls.erase(basicWalls.begin(),basicWalls.end()); has UB.  The iterators passed to erase must come from the container you are calling erase on.

Are you looking for std::set_difference?

or std::erase_if

@Jarod42
the question is not about basicwalls or cornerwalls being copy, I'm trying to delete elements in cornerwalls that has the same elements in basicwalls

cppreference.com is a better source (albeit harder to navigate, IMHO). It specifies Removes the elements in the range [first, last), which must be a valid range in *this

Per cppreference:

Removes the elements in the range [first, last), which must be a valid range in *this.

[basicWalls.begin(),basicWalls.end()) is not a valid range in cornerWalls, since the iterators come from different container.

If you want to remove from cornerWalls all elements that exist in basicWalls, you need std::erase_if() from C++20:
std::erase_if(cornerWalls, [&basicWalls](const Vector2i& v){return basicWalls.contains(v); });

or before C++20 do it manually with erase:
for(const Vector2i& v: basicWalls)
{
    cornerWalls.erase(v);
}


std::set_difference requires sorted ranges, so it cannot be used with std::unordered_set.

Also, be aware that %d is wrong specifier for std::size_t in printf. Lying to the function about type of data can end very badly. Use C++ output streams instead:
std::cout << "basic walls size: " << basicWalls.size() << ", corner walls size: " << cornerWalls.size() << "\n";

Or if you really need printf for some reason, use correct specifiers:
printf("basic walls size: %zu, corner walls size: %zu\n", basicWalls.size(), cornerWalls.size());


I think it's worth mentioning that erase_if takes O(n) time with n being the number of elements in cornerWalls, while the loop takes O(m) time with m being the number of elements in basicWalls. So the optimal choice depends on the specific set sizes

In theory, if we could constrain both to use the same hash table size and random access hash buckets, a intersection could be calculated in O(intersection) lg((m+n) time.  But that ain't happening with std unordered containers
